# How to Check field or uncheck field in Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a input which needs to be show color as white background when empty text. and when text  inside the field want to show the yellow color background.

some basic JS code is here to see the reference

```
jsfiddle.net/2Xgfr/87/
```

It has to work for multiple input fields

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The short way by using ng-class + css**:

*HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
     <div class='form-group'>
   <label>Field 1</label>
  <input type='text'  
         ng-class="{true: 'c2', false:'c1'}[f1.length > 0]" 
         ng-model='f1'
         >
 </div>
</div>
```

*css*

```
.c1{background: white;}
.c2{background: yellow;}
```

Demo 1 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ri4reFWQHyuFugb55Cdt?p=preview)</kbd>

**The short way by using ng-style**

(I suggest this one)

*HTML only*

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
     <div class='form-group'>
   <label>Field 1</label>
  <input type='text'  
         ng-style="{true: {background: 'yellow'}, false: {background: 'white'}}[f1.length > 0]" 
        ng-model='f1'
        >
 </div>
</div>
```

Demo 2 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/523oYNgK7HApsb5NIVpD?p=preview)</kbd>

**$watch + ng-style**

You can use [ng-style](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angStyle)  and `$watch` to manage color style.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);

app.controller("Controller", ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.mystyle = {
    background: 'white'
  };

  $scope.$watch('f1', function () {
    if($scope.f1.length > 0){
       $scope.mystyle.background = 'yellow';
    }
    else{
      $scope.mystyle.background = 'white';
    }
});
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
     <div class='form-group'>
   <label>Field 1</label>
  <input type='text' ng-model='f1' ng-style="mystyle">
 </div>
```

Demo 3 <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R6j39S8D8IY7YlO6Y2DQ?p=preview)</kbd>

*As a side note*:

Its not good practice to manipulate/update with DOM into controller

Comment: can you show a example how it get proper output. i am new to Angular.js

Comment: added example, see above

Comment: Hi, I am doing input validation on Angular.js but it's fine for one field validation but how to do the code if i have more input fields.
Here is the my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Z6RRhPvbZNdlG9S9YYTP?p=preview

hope i can get good solution from your end...